# Storage of portable (but bulky) power tools

Tags: powertools, storage

So in the course of this renno, I've acquired a few larger/more bulky power tools (portable table saw, compound sliding miter/stand, 13" planer, etc..). Currently I am using the soon-to-be kitchen pantry for storing them.  When the pantry is being finished in a few weeks, the tools need to find a new home.  My options are:

1. Basement utility room.  Small room that houses the water pressure tank, water heater and furnace.  Has drains in the floor, but can get a tad bit damp.  I'd put in some hooks/shelves to keep the tools off the floor.  However, storing the tools here would make this room VERY cramped, and make accessing the utilities in there, a bit of a hassle.
2. Detached Garage.  Very large garage, tons of room, nice and dry.  The downside- it is unheated, and I am in Minnesota, so it will get quite cold in the winter.

Thoughts on the best route to go?  Will extreme cold damage the tools?  If so, they'll stay indoors, and I'll deal with the inconvenience in the utility room.  If not, the garage seems like an ideal place to store them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd be tempted to keep them in the garage, where it sounds like they could be used in a pinch, even though its cold. I don't think the cold would hurt them.

Comment: Moisture is almost always the culprit in non-accidental tool failure. It corrodes so many different, and crucial parts. Bearings, electronics, trigger mechanisms, blades/cutting surfaces, etc. If you're worried about storage, a good rubdown with a non drying oil, cover with plastic sheeting/bags and toss in some silica for good measure. Does wonders for storing things like my pen lathe that I don't keep out always.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Option 2 - and then use that reasoning to insulate and heat the garage! :D

In all seriousness, I am currently having that dilemma in my condo - owning a bunch of power tools with nowhere to store them all conveniently.  I've divided my tools up into two groups, one that gets used regularly (impact driver, drill) and stuff that doesn't (bigger tools).  The regularly used stuff goes in a hall closet in my tool bag - the rest of it gets stuck in our storage room downstairs.

Seems to be a decent compromise.  Otherwise I'd just keep everything in the garage; back when I lived in Spokane, Washington which gets down below freezing a lot I'd store my power tools in my garage and it wasn't problematic.

Comment: I ended up with the same compromise when we lived in a condo. Having a house is so nice for that reason alone.